# Rails app not working after downgraded from 4.0.0 to 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downgraded my Rails from 4.0.0 to 3.2.9 for one of my applications.

**Gemfile**

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem "rails", "~> 3.2.9"

# OTHERS
gem 'will_paginate'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
```

problem is, whenever I run `rails server` now it acts as if the application does not exist.

```
my@ubuntu:~/ruby/myapp$ rails s
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
...
```

**why is it happening, and how do I fix this?**

Comment: Upgrading to rails 4.0.0 makes the application work again. The app was initially built as a 4.0.0 application.

Comment: seems gemset is missing, try this: rvm gemset create rails3.2; rvm gemset use rails3.2; gem install rails -v 3.2.9; cd your-app; bundle update;